# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'returndata'

Tags: python, return-value, python-import

I have created a model in Python, to predict a result based on an image, when run it I get the following error:

The following error:

```
(base) MacBook-Air:Backend desktop$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from returndata import Content
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'returndata'
```

**I can't find anything related.**
This is the code of my model:
**app.py:**

```
import os
from flask import *
from returndata import Content
import predict as pred
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/UPLOADFOLDER'

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp'])



TOPIC_DICT = Content()
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = "static"
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/skin/')
def skin():
    return render_template("skinLesion.html")

@app.route('/retinopathy/')
def retinopathy():
    return render_template("retinopathy.html")


@app.route('/upload/', methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print(request.files)
            d = Response("Error",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            d = Response("No filename",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return pred.classify(filename, response=True)

@app.route('/uploadPC/', methods=["POST"])
def uploadPC():
    print("in upload")
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print(request.files)
            d = Response("Error",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            d = Response("No filename",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            category, confidence = pred.classify(filename, response=False)
            print(category, confidence)
            confidence = '%.2f'%(confidence*100)
            if category == "malignant":
                return render_template("malignant.html", confidence=confidence)
            else:
                return render_template("benign.html", confidence=confidence)




@app.route('/uploadDiabetic/', methods=["POST"])
def uploadDiabetic():

    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print(request.files)
            d = Response("Error",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            d = Response("No filename",status=201,mimetype='application/json')
            return d
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return pred.classify_retino(filename, response=True)
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance.

What should I you change?

Comment: What is `returndata`?  Is it a module you wrote and are trying to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using "returndata" and "TOPIC_DICT = Content()"?

Python cannot import this module. Either install it or give the right path where to import the module from.

Comment: This would be a better comment than an answer. See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: I cannot comment. Should I delete this answer if it's considered more as a comment?